# How to select all elements except specific one?

Tags: php, html

I have a structure like this:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <a class="test">one</a>
    </span>
    <a>two</a>
    <a>three</a>
</div>
```

And here is my code:

```
$data = $html->find('div', 0);
foreach($data->find('a') as $article){
  echo $word .= $article->plaintext."<br>";
}
```

And here is current result:

```
one
two
three
```

And here is expected result:

```
two
three
```

---

As you see in the above result, I want to select all `<a>` element except the one that has `test` classname. How can I do that?

**Note:** I use [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) PHP library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion (didn't test it):

```
$data = $html->find('div', 0);
foreach($data->find('a') as $article){
  if($article->getAttribute('class') != 'test'){
    echo $word .= $article->plaintext."<br>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not use this library before, but maybe:

```
->find('a[class!=test]')-
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find => attribute filters tab

Comment: `->find('a[class!="test"]')-` ?

Comment: Still doesn't work. But yes, according to that link, your approach should be correct, but really I don't know why it doesn't work, Anyway thank you. +1 for your effort